# How do you find out the number of rows that is needed for the truth table?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How do you find out the number of rows that is needed for the truth table?

For example, for $A\implies B$ is a $4\ \text{x}\ 2$ table. What about if we want to make a table for, say,

**$A\implies(P\implies R)$**?

Comment: The number is $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of propositional letters in the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you need a table with $f(n)$ rows to track through all the possible assignments of truth-values to $n$ variables. Then if we want to add another variable $X$, and track through all the possible assignments of  truth-values to $X$ plus $n$ other variables, then you'll need to consider the case where $X$ is true, combined with the $f(n)$ assignments to the other variables, and then consider the case where $X$ is false, combined again with the $f(n)$ assignments to the other variables. That means $f(n + 1) = 2f(n)$.

Since $f(1) = 2$ (obviously!), it follows that $f(n) = 2^n$.